# Parse an asymmetrical string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, parsing

I am trying to parse string:

```
'local:\n    ----------\n    instance_A:\n        ----------\n        release:\n            3-17-0\n    instance_B:\n        ----------\n        release:\n            3-16-0\n    log_level:\n        debug\n    primary_instance:\n        A\n'
```

to become something like

```
{"instance_A":"3-17-0","instance_B":"3-16-0"}
```

The issue is that the dashes are 'asymmetrical' e.g. they are different for instance_A and instance_B so that when i do something like this:

```
"".join(a.split()).replace('----------','')[6:-33]
```

(which I don't think is a good approach anyways due to [6:-33]) I'm getting

```
'instance_A:release:3-17-0instance_B:release:3-16-0'
```

which would've been OK if there was a delimiter between 3-17-0instance_B

Please suggest a pythonic way to parse that string, and evaluate the current approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this like that:

```
v = "".join(a.split()).replace('----------','').replace('release:','')[6:-33]
v = v[:17]+':'+v[17:]
i = iter(v.split(':'))
d = dict(zip(i,i))
```

This works, even though it's ugly as hell. If anyone could provide an advice to make this better lookin it would be really appreciated